# decimal output for Tensorflor model when it should be a boolean (1/0)

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, tensorflow2.0, data-analysis

I have a model that takes in the boxscore for each NBA team in the 2015-2016 and then outputs if they won or lost (1/0). Here are some data points already numerically encoded.
[image]

(for reference the WL column gets dropped and becomes my label/target).

Now my problem is that my model gives predictions within a range (0.49-0.50~) instead of a 1 or 0. I have tried to mess around within .compile() as I believe thats most likely where my problem is but no dice. code below w/ some model predictions. appreciate any
help and feedback

[image]
[image]

[image]

update edit:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing binary classification, you don't want to use Mean Squared Error as your loss function. So first thing I'd change is the loss function to `'binary_crossentropy'`.

You could play around with the optimizer as well as I see you are using SGD, but I'd start with `'adam'`. I would also use `'relu'` for activation functions for input and hidden layers. Only have the output layer of `'sigmoid'` or `'softmax'`. All this stuff is hyperparamter tuning and testing that you can play with later, but the main thing here is your loss function. So you may want something like this.

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

or

```
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['binary_accuracy'])
```

Lastly, you will not necessarily get 0s and 1s. You are going to get decimals, and you may need to figure out a thresh, default being 0.5.

So any output where output

```
y >= 0 and y < 0.5 -----> 0
v >= 0.5 and y <=1 -----> 1
```

Comment: appreciate the explanation. i ended up working backwords with this tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification but instead of clothings items 1-10, i did 0-1 and treated it as win or loss. As for the getting decimals, I was able to get 0 and 1 off the bat with the tutorial. Thanks again, reading you comment is helping me understand where I was going wrong